# How to use ActiveX ocx file generated by Delphi in a WInForm project

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi, vcl

I'm trying to use Delphi to pack VCL components into an ocx file and put them into a WinForm project. But when I add the ocx file into the toolbox, it's shown as a gray status. Only in the .Net FrameWork projects can this ocx works properly.
I wonder how to make the ocx files work in WinForm projects or if it's possible.

Comment: Because .NET Core doesn't support ancient, unsafe and obsolete technologies like OCX.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to use ActiveX in a WinForm project.
Just an example: https://github.com/TrueConf/SDK/tree/master/Windows/winforms-examples

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).